# Efficient way to split files based on size

Tags: python, perl, unix, split

I do splitting of my zipped input file which is of 10 GB normally as follows,

```
zcat file|split -b 1024m - file.part
```

The above command will create 10 split files for 10 GB input. 
Here comes my requirement, this process in Unix box takes 15-30 mins depends on server load. Do we have any other technology which does splitting in faster way? Maybe in Perl or Python..

Comment: According to your tests, are the performances bound by the CPU or by disk access?

Comment: first result in google: http://www.techiecorner.com/107/how-to-split-large-file-into-several-smaller-files-linux/ . you shouldn't use `zcat | `

Comment: @Elazar hello dude. they just told what I have used (split command in unix). Please read my requirement and respond.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux no. My requirement is to complete them in 2 to 3 mins.Is it purely based on server size and utlization?

Comment: @Mari you are not using split, but `cat`ing the whole file to standart output, and only *then* you split it.

Comment: @Elazar I agree with you. So you are saying that if I unzip the file then sort it, performance will be higher?

Comment: 10GB to read, uncompress and write back in 3 minutes. Roughly speaking that give a throughput of 1.5 Gb/s. Pretty high, no?

Comment: if you want several zip files, you are bounded by the time it takes you to unzip it. Not the "split" part. If all you need is to split and rejoin, you don't need to unzip it.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux yes I know it's kind of greedy approach.

Comment: @Elazar So I guess if I do split -b 1024m file_name it will be faster. because am avoiding zcat and piping it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to uncompress the input.

`zipsplit` (part of `Info-ZIP`) is available on most *nix distributions.

As per [man zipsplit](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zipsplit.html):

```
zipsplit - split a zipfile into smaller zipfiles
```

Or if using split:

```
split -b 1024m file file.part
```

would split `file` into `file.partaa`, `file.partab` ...

In order to create the original file from the split ones, do

```
cat file.part* | gzip -dc > outfile
```

Comment: But my files are .gz files. @devnull Do we have anything like zipsplit for .gz files?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly limited by hardware here; a Python or Perl implementation is not likely to work around this.

If you are limited by CPU, then using the Python or Perl bindings on to the same compression libraries won't make any difference.

If you are limited by disk IO, then using the Python or Perl IO operation won't make your disks any faster.